# How do I send a variable from Express.js backend to React.js frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to send my variable 'backEndResponse' with its value from my Express.js backend to my React.js Frontend. I am not quite sure how to send a variable from the backend to the frontend. I have searched around and can't find any good resources. I would appreciate any help.

Express.js Backend

```
function getcookie(req) {
    var authCookie = req.headers.cookie;
    if (authCookie = req.headers.cookie) {
        try {
            return authCookie
                .split('; ')
                .find(row => row.startsWith('Auth='))
                .split('=')[1];
        } finally {
            if (authCookie = result) {
                backEndResponse = true
                console.log(backEndResponse);
                console.log(result);
            } else {
                backEndResponse = false
                console.log(backEndResponse);
                console.log(result);
            }

        }
    } else {

    }
}

app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
    getcookie(req)

    if (backEndResponse) {
        res.json(backEndResponse); // OR json({ message: "Authorised" })
      } else {
        res.json(backEndResponse); // OR json({ message: "Unauthorised" })
    }
});
```

Frontend React.js

```
    const useAuth = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState();

      useEffect(() => {
          const fetchAuthData = () => {
            const result = axios('http://localhost:5000/auth');

            console.log(result)
            setData(result.data);
            
          };

          fetchAuthData()
      }, []);

      
    // Logic to check if backEndResponse is true or false
    if (data) {
        const authorized = {loggedIn: true}
        return authorized && authorized.loggedIn;
    } else {
        const authorized = {loggedIn: false}
        return authorized && authorized.loggedIn;
    }
  }


const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
    const isAuth = useAuth();
    return isAuth ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}
```

Comment: I think you just need `res.json(backEndResponse)`

Comment: Then how do I retrieve it on the frontend? Do I just set backEndResponse = backEndResponse?

Comment: The response will be in `res.data`

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to send a variable directly, rather you will send a payload in a certain shape that best represents the data suited to the applications needs. To send a response payload in an express route use something like the following:

```js
app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
  // do some logic for `backEndResponse`...
  res.json(backEndResponse);
});
```

If you were intending to provide more information in the response such as HTTP headers differing based on the of `backEndResponse` then you might consider:

```js
app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
  // do some logic for `backEndResponse`...

  // send HTTP Ok if true, otherwise Bad Request
  // consider handling 400 and/or 500 errors too
  if (backEndResponse) {
    res.status(200).json(true); // OR json({ message: "Authorised" })
  } else {
    res.status(401).json(false); // OR json({ message: "Unauthorised" })
  }
});
```

A component fetching the above endpoint would be similar to:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAuthData = async () => {
      const result = await axios('http://localhost:5000/auth');

      setData(result.data); // true/false OR { message: "Authorised" }
    };

    fetchAuthData();
  }, []);

  // display payload
  return (<div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>)
}
```

There is an opportunity to refactor the above into a custom hook should you find the need to reuse the functionality across multiple components.

Comment: `true` or `false` are perfectly valid JSON responses, you do not need to respond with an object literal

Comment: @Phil very true and your point aligns to the question. I have updated the answer to reflect your comments

Comment: I was more meaning that `backEndResponse` is a Boolean in OP's question so you can use `.json(backEndResponse)`

Comment: @Phil you are right again. I think because I added in the parts with `.status(200)` that perhaps I was overstepping what the question asked. So a payload of `.json(backEndResponse)` might be a 200 response no matter if the value is true or false.

Comment: @Phil I have updated my Code above to run like the code provided in this example the issue I now face is that "result.data" returns undefined unless I add async and await to my "fetchAuthData" function then "result.data" returns true or false. However, I get  "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.". If I add the async and await to "fetchAuthData".

Answer (score 0):

axios request is async function, so you should do like that,

```js
const useAuth = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/auth', {
      withCredentials: true
    })
    return true
  } catch (e) {
    return false
  }
};
```